# In "Pandorum", what made it so difficult for the awakened crew to realize the ship's location?

Tags: pandorum

As Bower and Payton adventure through the Elysium, they slowly reveal the clues that ultimately lead to the realization that

> they have been underwater the entire length of the film.

I understand that the ship was designed for hypersleep and the computer system wasn't helpful in determining their location, but we do know for sure that the crew ejection systems functioned perfectly, so there was at least one way to exit/escape the ship. You would think there would also be windows available for crew members and passengers to look at the stars upon awakening

> (unless it was designed to release only upon arrival, which leaves me with another question as to why that didn't happen when they arrived on Tanis in the first place).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would you put windows on a starship where one, there is nothing to look at and two, most of the people on the ship are unconscious?

Add to that they were locked out of the (proper) bridge until the final few moments (when they do see out the windows and realize where they are), and I don't feel like they cheated in this movie.

As for why the ship didn't begin whatever automated deployment routines it had: the lead character had damaged/sabotaged them in a fit of insanity.

Comment: Hmm, I might have to watch this one again over the weekend - I don't remember the sabotage.